# Air conditioning available on the morning train Budapest -> Romania

Tags: trains, romania, budapest

Due to the rising summer temperatures I'd like to know whether the train that departs from 9:05 in the morning from Budapest (Hungary) with direction Brasov (Romania) has climatization that works?

I saw some report that the wagon circulating on the route Budapest - Brasov had problems recently, so I'm unsure what to expect. (probably it would also be interesting to have information about the opposite direction from Romania to Hungary, as I think they use essentially the same vagons).

If anyone recently rode this train, I'd also be interested to know how full it was.

Comment: It is the start of school holidays in many parts of Europe, you can expect all trains to be full, even when they were not in previous weeks (or even days.)

Comment: Air condition breaks all the time. It's hard to predict if it will work in a certain cart on a given date in the future

Comment: @Willeke In Hungary school holidays have long started, as they have in Romania. I think what you said mostly applies only to western European countries? Also, the pandemic, the geopolitical situation etc. influence the passenger numbers strongly, so a most up-to-date account would really be helpful.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Could you please give me some context (when did you go last time on (parts of) this route, how often do you go)?

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted, as far as I can tell my question falls exactly in line with the topics discussed here.

Comment: I do not understand either, this can be answered and I did. You will not like it but it is the truth.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr: The chance of a working AC on a Hungarian train is low and it's getting lower with every passing day.

You are in luck information wise because an exceptionally good writeup on the state of affairs was just published two weeks ago: http://www.regionalbahn.hu/2022/07/magyar-vasut-2022.html run it through Google Translate, I guess.

For air conditioning it mentions

> In recent weeks, international trains have started to run out of cars, and the technical condition of the vehicles that are still running is dancing on a knife's edge, especially in terms of air conditioning.

and also

> it is a sad proof of climate change that the air conditioners of the older passenger cars specified in the nineties cannot withstand the current summer temperature and regularly break down due to constantly running at peak performance.

Expect massive delays, crowding and overall miserable circumstances.

If you don't want to do the train, there are a few relatively good options.

1. Car share. The main car share in Hungary is [oszkar](https://utitars.oszkar.com/erkorszag-RO/honnan-Budapest/hova-Bra%C8%99ov/indorszag-HU/). But finding a car which goes as far as Brașov will require a lot of luck. Try Târgu Mureș and maybe a [bus](https://www.autogari.ro/Transport/TarguMures-Brasov?zi=2022-07-19&pas=1-0-0-0-0) but see next point.
2. Fly to Bucharest with Tarom or Târgu Mureș with Wizz Air and then find your way from there. This is another question for someone more familiar with current Romanian situation than me. I do not know, for example, how is the AC on the train from Bucharest to Brasov.

The best option is to wait until November when the airport is scheduled to open.

Comment: There are a few private train companies in Romania that offer very good traveling conditions in newer trains, like https://www.astratranscarpatic.ro/, https://www.softrans.ro/, or https://transferoviarcalatori.ro/. They are not covering the entire country, but at least from Bucharest to Brasov, or from Timisoara to Brasov there are a few options.